# List of useful external tools [closed from site]

Tags: discussion

Hello!

I was thinking that it would be great to make a compilation of external TeX/LaTeX tools available.

I'll update this post as people answer and vote...

Happy texing!

Comment: I'm sure some people would find this useful, but I wonder if it's the kind of question we want on the site? I imagine that whatever external tools are presented here would also pop up as answers to "How do I _blah_?"-type questions, and most people are more likely to find them there.

Comment: This type of question begs to someone list all editors out there.....

Maybe a more specific question about specialized, obscure and not-well known tools is more appropriate question.

Comment: A little like the  "Hidden features of <language>" on SO, I suppose... even those are controversial. They're definitely useful, but still the question is, are those the kinds of things we want people to see flourishing when the public beta starts? I think this may deserve a meta-discussion.

Comment: Exactly what @David said; there's no question here, and the answers are going to be for particular random things. The [one answer so far](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238/list-of-useful-external-tools/239#239) fits far better on [How to look up a math symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol), and that's where people will actually find it useful

Comment: @David That's the perfect example, because those are getting closed these days; the only reason they exist is SO was lax about that kind of thing when they started out, and now it's ridiculously difficult to get rid of them. We should decide early whether or not we want random summary of information posts

Comment: In that case: hereby [meta-ized](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38/should-we-allow-summary-of-information-posts) ;-) (@YuppieNetworking: no offense intended! It's a good idea to get these issues out in the open early.)

Answer (score 2):

[Dextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) lets you doodle a symbol and it will tell you which command does it